# I can't remember one of the words in my 24-word mnemonic phrase

Tags: wallet, mnemonic-seed, wallet-import-format

I wanted to import my mnemonic phrase to my new phone but I can't remember one of the words being asked that I wrote down. Is there any way to get that one? I remember all the other words.

Comment: https://github.com/ZenGo-X/mnemonic-recovery Scroll down for instructions

Comment: Can you answer the question @MCCCS rather than answer in the comments? Or alternatively if the question is a duplicate, mark it as a duplicate. I don't think there is obvious duplicate from a brief search.

Comment: Maybe this https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/93697/have-10-of-12-of-my-mnemonic-along-with-the-btc-address-how-can-i-automate-reco